# Storyboards create modal view accessible from anywhere

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I need to create a modal "flow" within my app. It is made of two "scenes", these are both UITableViewController subclasses.

The user will be able to push and pop between these two table views.

At any point they will be able to press "Done" (in a nav bar) and dismiss the entire modal view to go back to where they were.

This whole modal flow needs to be accessible from several places in the app. I don't really want to create multiple modal segues to this.

My question is, creating this in a storyboard, would you create a whole new storyboard for this flow (I don't like this).

Would you just create multiple modal segues?

Should I create this flow in the same storyboard file but as a separate entity accessible by the identifier?

Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it would be easier to use a single storyboard, but not create multiple segues everywhere. You can programmatically present the view controller pretty easily:

```
MyViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
// set any properties on vc here, if necessary to pass it any data
[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

You could place all this code in a helper method to reuse this code more easily, maybe a class method like this:

```
@interface MyViewController ...
+ (void)presentNewViewControllerModally;
...
@end
```

Tapping the done button:

```
[self.window.rootViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Note that if there's a good chance you'll never see this modal view controller, you could place that view controller in a separate xib file instead of in the storyboard, and I *think* that could make things more efficient (storyboard remains more lightweight). In this case, just replace the `instantiteViewControllerWithIdentifier` message above with:

```
[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeNib" bundle:nil];
```

...and the rest of the code is the same. I've used this technique for a "login" view controller that would only occasionally need to be presented.